# Rails and Gmail SMTP, how to use a custom from address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, gmail, actionmailer

I've got my Rails (2.1) app setup to send email via Gmail, however whenever I send an email no matter what I set the from address to in my ActionMailer the emails always come as if sent from my Gmail email address. Is this a security restriction they've put in place at Gmail to stop spammers using their SMTP?

Note: I've tried both of the following methods within my ActionMailer (just in case):

```
@from = me@mydomain.com
from 'me@mydomain.com'
```

Comment: Have you added the addresses you are trying to send from to your GMail account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's just something Gmail does when mail is sent through its SMTP, as it was mentioned that they do this on a tutorial about using their SMTP to send mail.

Comment: However, you can allow Gmail to send emails with one of your other email addresses in the From: header by adding it under Gmail's Settings > Accounts.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely to stop people trying to send email from addresses that Google can't verify that the sender owns. This is fairly common amongst mail providers, and is probably a safeguard to stop people using Google's services for sending spam.

Answer (score 3):

I think I tried and failed in the past myself, but I did just come across this on the gmail site: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?ctx=gmail&hl=en&answer=22370

Looks like you can specify a custom "From" address within gmail, and perhaps at that point, see if setting @from will work (now that gmail knows about your custom from address).