# ROR : send email using different mail id at different time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, sender

I m new at ROR, so it may be a silly ques.
I'm using ActionMailer to send a mail to any reciepient.
Initially i have tried it using gmail smtp setting.
But in that everytime the mail is sent, it is from the same mail_id.
But in my application I want sender to be different at different time.
So, is it possible to do it using ActionMailer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what version of Rails you are on (it shouldn't matter for this one), but this question has already been answered here: [Rails and Gmail SMTP, how to use a custom from address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109520/rails-and-gmail-smtp-how-to-use-a-custom-from-address)