# Sending email in django.

Tags: django, email, smtp

I have a page where people can submit an email. It works, but I receive all emails from it saying that they are from myself.

Here's the view:

```
def signup(request):
  if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
        recipients = ['illuminatirebellion@gmail.com']

        from django.core.mail import send_mail
        send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
else:
     form = SignUpForm() # An unbound form
return render_to_response('signup.html', {'form': form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And the settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'illuminatirebellion@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
MANAGERS = ADMINS
```

Comment: Have you tried using the keywords? i.e. `send_mail(subject=subject, message=message, from_email=sender, recipient_list=recipients)` Just a sanity check, it should work as is.

Comment: does not work it says that i sent it from myself

Comment: Well, `recipient` is you, and sender is you also. So, shouldn't it be `YOU`?

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of [`send_mail()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs#send-mail) appears to be correct.

Assuming that Gmail is your SMTP vendor, it seems that Gmail does not support using custom `From:` email addresses.

Relevant:

- [Rails and Gmail SMTP, how to use a custom from address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109520/rails-and-gmail-smtp-how-to-use-a-custom-from-address)
- [How to change from-address when using gmail smtp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server)